# Python Unicode problem: Getting google translate results into a csv

Tags: python, csv, unicode, export-to-csv

I'm attempting to write a python program to get google translate results from several languages and write them to a csv file.  Most of the code works, but I am hitting unicode issues.

Current code:

```
WordTable = open('Translated.csv', 'w', newline="", encoding = 'utf-8-sig')
WordWrite = unicodecsv.writer(WordTable)
for row in WordOut:

    print(row[0])
    row = row + [Translator().translate(row[0], src = 'en', dest='es').text]
    row = row + [Translator().translate(row[0], src = 'en', dest='ar').text]
    row = row + [Translator().translate(row[0], src = 'en', dest='zh-CN').text]
    row = row + [Translator().translate(row[0], src = 'en', dest='ru').text]
    print(len(row), row)
    WordWrite.writerow(row)
```

What I've tried after reading here and elsewhere:

1. current code:  results in "UnicodeEncodeError:  'charmap character can't encode characters'.  this also happens when no encode commands or options are used at all.
2. changing the translation lines to:

   ```
   row = row + [Translator().translate(row[0], src = 'en', dest='ru').text.encode('utf-8-sig')]
   ```

or equivalent:   Code runs, but spits out longer versions of "b'\xef\xbb\" etc.

Am also interested in an explanation of what is happening, if possible (what is in what format, when it gets changed, how it gets entered, etc.)  if possible.  the explanations I've read elsewhere can get confusing.

Edit:  This is in Python 3.4

Comment: Please provide an example of your `Translated.csv`

Comment: Please clarify two things: (1) Does the UnicodeEncodeError stem from the `print()` expression or from the `WordWrite.writerow()` line? (2) Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: Late addition:  After an attempt to retest everything to give a better answer, problem is mostly fixed.  Code below.

Answer (score 0):

After some retests, turns out this code works properly for the csv:

```
WordTable = open('Translated.csv', 'w', newline="", encoding = 'utf-8-sig')
WordWrite = csv.writer(WordTable)
for row in WordOut:

    print(row[0])
    row = row + [Translator().translate(row[0], src = 'en', dest='es').text]
    row = row + [Translator().translate(row[0], src = 'en', dest='ar').text]
    row = row + [Translator().translate(row[0], src = 'en', dest='zh-CN').text]
    row = row + [Translator().translate(row[0], src = 'en', dest='ru').text]
    #printing length or english alphabet works, but errors on special characters
WordWrite.writerow(row)
```

Cmd window doesn't like non-english alphabet, and if you are using this exact code.  Additional retests show:

1. using    ,encoding='utf8') in the open() function, .text in the translation, prints special characters in the csv file, but the wrong ones(spanish is fine, other three are not)
2. using no encoding at all in the open() function, .text in the translation function, gives a UnicodeEncodeError (the one listed above)
3. any type of encoding at all after the translation texts gives (As in, translationstuff.text.encoding('something') gives slash marks as an output in the csv file.  Example cell(meant to be Russian for North):   b'\xd0\xba \xd1\x81\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd1\x83'

What I think is happening (Am checking this for future situations, I don't know the programming that well):  Python 3 reads the text just fine.  If I try encoding the text, Python thinks it is regular text (this part is confusing) and sends this to the csv to give the slash sequences written above.  The csv doesn't normnally operate with non english characters , so will throw an error if I don't specifically write it in a different format (and the format has to obviously be the right one, or characters are wrong)

Comment: In Python 3, the csv module works just fine with text in any language. If the output file uses UTF-8 encoding, all characters should be written correctly (unless there's a problem in the input). If you see the wrong characters in the output file, it may be that the viewer has a wrong idea of the file encoding (ie. uses something other than UTF-8 for display).